# Selecting specific fields from a output command.

Tags: command-line, bash, debian, shell

```
top -o %MEM -b > file.txt
```

time1 = Mar 27 21:27:55

time2 = Mar 28 20:27:32

I need to only redirect the output of the command `top -o %MEM -b` to output.txt

if time1 <= date1 < =time2

where `time1`,`time2`,`date1` are the date I choose! I could use Unix time!

Is it possible in linux shell?

How can I do it? I should save the information in XML/JSON format instead of txt file!

Comment: where does values for `time1`, `time2` and `date` come from?

Comment: @rsm:`time1`,`time2`,`date1` are the date I choose!

Comment: ok, so  can you choose them in *unix time* (seconds since 1970-01-01)? it's much easier to work on numbers than on string respresentation of date.

Comment: @rsm: yes! I can convert it to unix time!

Comment: to keep things clean here, can you please ask about converting `top` output to XML/JSON in separate question, and leave this question as it was before?

Comment: @rsm: https://superuser.com/questions/1194437/how-to-save-the-output-of-top-command-in-xml-json-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern shells are programming languages, so you can use arithmetic to check for dates condition. However, `top` in batch mode runs until the iteration limit is reached, and once you start `top`, you can't check for dates condition. So you have to run `top` with iteration limit set to 1 and restart it in while loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
output_file="file.txt"
iteration_delay=5s
time1=1491004315
time2=3500000000
date1=`date +%s` #we initialize date1 with current unix time

while ((1)); do
    if (($time1 <= $date1 && $date1 <= $time2)); then
        top -o %MEM -b -n 1 >> $output_file
    fi
    sleep $iteration_delay
    # something should update date1, time1 or time2 here...?
done
```

EDIT:
To use this script, copy/paste it to for example mytop.sh file, set *executable* on it:

```
chmod +x mytop.sh
```

and then you can start it as usual, by:

```
./mytop.sh
```

To cancel, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

There is no visual indicator it's running and some people feel better when there is some output. If you want, you can add for example:

```
echo .
```

line in the script after `sleep` line, to print new dot on every iteration.

Comment: How can I run this script?

Comment: @EdS good point, please check my updated answer and let me know if there is something not clear now.

Comment: Thank you! That's clear! I posted another question: https://superuser.com/questions/1194437/how-to-save-the-output-of-top-command-in-xml-json-format

Comment: the script does not stop running...

Comment: @EdS use [ctrl] + [c] to stop the script (you might need to press it couple times).

Comment: but, it does not have no output file like file.txt